# How to pass _selectedValue as a props

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to pass selectedValue as a props please. I am supposed to pass the selectedValue as a props to the View screen where i am doing (selectedValue={props.selectedValue}).

So i am supposed to pass Dropdown to View.js as a props like this
(_selectedValue={props._selectedValue})

DropDown.js

```js
_selectedValue(index, item) {
    this.setState({ selectedText: item.name });
  }

  render(props) {
    return (
      <View>
        <RNPicker
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          dummyDataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          defaultValue={false}
          pickerTitle={"Country Picker"}
          showSearchBar={true}
          disablePicker={false}
          changeAnimation={"none"}
          searchBarPlaceHolder={"Search....."}
          showPickerTitle={true}
          searchBarContainerStyle={this.props.searchBarContainerStyle}
          pickerStyle={Styles.pickerStyle}
          pickerItemTextStyle={Styles.listTextViewStyle}
          selectedLabel={this.state.selectedText}
          placeHolderLabel={this.state.placeHolderText}
          selectLabelTextStyle={Styles.selectLabelTextStyle}
          placeHolderTextStyle={Styles.placeHolderTextStyle}
          dropDownImageStyle={Styles.dropDownImageStyle}
          selectedValue={(index, item) => this._selectedValue(index, item)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

This Index.js is where i am handling most of the signup logic plus validation and error handling, in viewProps I declared a variable to for the _selectedValue.

index.js

```js
import React, {useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import SignupView from './view';
import {validateFullName, validateEmail, validateUserType, validatePhoneNumber} from '../../../utils';
import {
  signUp,
  toggleAuthActionCreator,
} from '../../../store/actions/authActions';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {onSnackbar} from '../../../store/actions/layoutActions';

const Signup: () => React$Node = (props) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [firstname, setfirstName] = useState('');
  const [lastname, setlastName] = useState('');
  const [country, setCountry] = useState('');
  console.log({country});
  const [phoneNumber, setphoneNumber] = useState('');
  console.log({phoneNumber});
  const [usertype, setUsertype] = useState('Personal');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState({error: false, message: ''});
  const [passwordError, setPasswordError] = useState({
    error: false,
    message: '',
  });
  const [firstnameError, setfirstNameError] = useState({
    error: false,
    message: '',
  });
  const [lastnameError, setlastNameError] = useState({
    error: false,
    message: '',
  });
  const [countryError, setCountryError] = useState({
    error: false,
    message: '',
  });
  const [phoneNumberError, setphoneNumberError] = useState({
    error: false,
    message: '',
  });
  const [usertypeError, setUsertypeError] = useState({
    error: false,
    message: '',
  });

  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);

  const onChange = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    const {text, name, val, defaultCode} = data;
    if (name.toLowerCase() === 'email') {
      setEmail(text);
    } else if (name.toLowerCase() === 'password') {
      setPassword(text);
    } else if (name.toLowerCase() === 'first name') {
      setfirstName(text);
    } else if (name.toLowerCase() === 'last name') {
      setlastName(text);
    }else if (name.toLowerCase() === 'country') {
      setCountry(text);
    } else if (name.toLowerCase() === 'phone number') {
      setphoneNumber(text);
    } else  {
      setUsertype(text);
    } 
  };

  const onBlur = (name) => {
    setDisabled(!disabled);
    if (name.toLowerCase() === 'email') {
      const res = validateEmail(email);
      if (!res) {
        setEmailError({error: true, message: 'Please enter a valid email.'});
      } else {
        setEmailError({error: false, message: ''});
      }
    } else if (name.toLowerCase() === 'password') {
      if (password.length < 8) {
        setPasswordError({
          error: true,
          message: 'Password should have atleast 8 letters.',
        });
      } else {
        setPasswordError({error: false, message: ''});
      }
    } else if (name.toLowerCase() === 'first name') {
      if (!validateFullName(firstname)) {
        setfirstNameError({
          error: true,
          message: 'Please enter a valid first name.',
        });
      } else {
        setfirstNameError({error: false, message: ''});
      }
    } else if (name.toLowerCase() === 'lastname'){
      if (!validateFullName(lastname)) {
        setlastNameError({
          error: true,
          message: 'Please enter a valid last name.',
        });
      } else {
        setlastNameError({error: false, message: ''});
      }
    } else if (name.toLowerCase() === 'country') {
      if (!validateFullName(country)) {
        setCountryError({
          error: true,
          message: 'Please enter a valid country.',
        });
      } else {
        setCountryError({error: false, message: ''});
      }
    } else if (phoneNumber.toLowerCase() === 'phone number') {
      if (!validatePhoneNumber(phoneNumber)) {
        setphoneNumberError({
          error: true,
          message: 'Please enter a valid phone number.',
        });
      } else {
        setphoneNumberError({error: false, message: ''});
      }
    } else  {
      if (name.length <= 1) {
        setUsertypeError({
          error: true,
          message: 'Please enter a valid usertype.',
        });
      } else {
        setUsertypeError({error: false, message: ''});
      }
    } 
  };



  const onCheckToggle = () => {
    setChecked(!checked);
    // console.log(setChecked(!checked));
  };

  const navigateToSignin = () => {
    props.navigation.navigate('Signin');
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    try {
      if (
        firstname.trim() &&
        !firstnameError.error &&
        lastname.trim() &&
        !lastnameError.error &&
        email.trim() &&
        !emailError.error &&
        password.trim() &&
        !passwordError.error &&
        country.trim() &&
        !countryError.error &&
        phoneNumber.trim() &&
        !phoneNumberError.error &&
        usertype.trim() &&
        !usertypeError.error
      ) {
        if (!checked) {
          props.showAlert('Please agree to Terms & Conditions to continue.');
          return;
        }
        let Personal = '1'
        let usertype = Personal

        setLoading(true);
        const SIGNUP_DATA = {
          email,
          firstname: firstname,
          lastname: lastname,
          country: country,
          phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
          usertype: usertype,
          password,
          retypePassword: password,
        };
        console.log({SIGNUP_DATA})

        signUp(
          SIGNUP_DATA,
          console.log(SIGNUP_DATA),
          (res) => {
            console.log('res of SIGNUP -->', res);
            setLoading(true);
            props.showAlert('An email have been send to your account. Please verify to login into your account.');
          },
          (err) => {
            console.log('err of SIGNUP -->', err);
            setLoading(false);
          },
          props.navigation.navigate('Signin')
        );
      } else {
        props.showAlert('Please fill all fields with valid data.');
      }//console.log(signUp());
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('e in signup -->', e);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const viewProps = {
    email,
    password,
    checked,
    loading,
    onChange,
    onCheckToggle,
    navigateToSignin,
    emailError,
    passwordError,
    onBlur,
    firstname,
    lastname,
    firstnameError,
    lastnameError,
    country,
    phoneNumber,
    usertype,
    countryError,
    phoneNumberError,
    usertypeError,
    onSubmit,
    disabled,
    onChangeText: setphoneNumber,
    _selectedValue: setCountry,
  };
  return <SignupView {...viewProps} />;
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    open: state.layoutReducer.snackbarState,
    message: state.layoutReducer.snackbarMessage,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    toggleAuth: (data) => dispatch(toggleAuthActionCreator(data)),
    showAlert: (message) => dispatch(onSnackbar(message)),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Signup);
```

Signup View.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import CustomInput from '../../../components/TextInput';
import AccountType from '../../../components/TextInput/accountType';
import Checkbox from '../../../components/Checkbox';
import AuthLayout from '../../../components/AuthLayout';
import PhoneInput from '../../../components/PhoneInput';
import DropDown from '../../../components/DropDown';
import ListComponent from '../../../components/ListComponent';
import {color, font} from '../../../../theme';

const SignupView = (props) => {
  const layoutProps = {
    heading: 'Please create an account',
    buttonLabel: 'Sign Up',
    clickText: 'Already have an account?',
    onAuthToggle: props.navigateToSignin,
    onPress: props.onSubmit,
    page: 'Signup',
    loading: props.loading,
  };
  return (
    <>
      <AuthLayout {...layoutProps}>
        <CustomInput
          label="First Name"
          value={props.firstname}
          onChange={props.onChange}
          onBlur={props.onBlur}
          errorText={props.firstnameError.message}
          error={props.firstnameError.error}
        />
        <CustomInput
          label="Last Name"
          value={props.lastname}
          onChange={props.onChange}
          onBlur={props.onBlur}
          errorText={props.lastnameError.message}
          error={props.lastnameError.error}
        />
        <CustomInput
          label="Email"
          errorText={props.emailError.message}
          error={props.emailError.error}
          onBlur={props.onBlur}
          value={props.email}
          onChange={props.onChange}
        />
        <CustomInput
          label="Password"
          error={props.passwordError.error}
          errorText={props.passwordError.message}
          isSecure={true}
          onBlur={props.onBlur}
          value={props.password}
          onChange={props.onChange}
        />
        {/* <CustomInput
          label="Country"
          value={props.country}
          onChange={props.onChange}
          onBlur={props.onBlur}
          errorText={props.countryError.message}
          error={props.countryError.error}
        /> */}
        <DropDown
          label = "Country"
          value={props.country}
          _selectedValue={props._selectedValue}
          selectedText={props.selectedText}
          searchBarContainerStyle={props.searchBarContainerStyle}
          error
        />
        {/* <Input
          label="Phone Number"
          value={props.phoneNumber}
          onChange={props.onChange}
          onBlur={props.onBlur}
          isNumber
          errorText={props.phoneNumberError.message}
          error={props.phoneNumberError.error}
        /> */}
        <PhoneInput
          label="Phone Number"
          value={props.phoneNumber}
          onChangeText={props.onChangeText}
          onBlur={props.onBlur}
          errorText={props.phoneNumberError.message}
          error={props.phoneNumberError.error}
        />
        <AccountType
          // label="Personal Account"
          value={props.usertype}
          onChange={props.onChange}
          onBlur={props.onBlur}
          isNumber
          errorText={props.usertypeError.message}
          error={props.usertypeError.error}
        />

        {/* <ListComponent
          label="Account Type 2"
          value={props.usertype}
        /> */}

        <View style={styles.actionWrapper}>
          <View style={styles.checkboxWrapper}>
            <Checkbox checked={props.checked} onPress={props.onCheckToggle} />
            <Text style={styles.checkboxText}>
              I agree with{' '}
              <Text style={styles.checkboxTextBold}>Terms & Conditions</Text>
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </AuthLayout>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  actionWrapper: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  checkboxWrapper: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  checkboxText: {
    fontSize: 13,
    color: color.primary,
    fontFamily: font.regular,
    textAlignVertical: 'center',
  },
  checkboxTextBold: {
    fontFamily: font.bold,
  },
  forgetText: {
    fontSize: 13,
    color: color.primary,
    fontFamily: font.regular,
    marginTop: 8,
    width: 160,
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
});

export default SignupView;
```

Comment: `selectedValue={this._selectedValue}`? What's wrong with your code?

Comment: What is `selectedValue`? Do you need to actually pass `this.state.selectedText` to the `selectedValue` prop versus what looks to be a callback handler, i.e. `selectedValue={this.state.selectedText}`? What exactly is the issue? Also, `render` doesn't receive any arguments. Tip, sorting your props alphabetically goes a long way in JSX readability.

Comment: @DrewReese selectedValue is the value selected by the user from the component dropdown. so i have passed this to a main class component where i am meant to receive it as a selectedValue={props.selectedValue} in the input dropdown fields. and i am getting this error TypeError: _this2.state._selectedValue is not a function. (In '_this2.state._selectedValue(index, item)', '_this2.state._selectedValue' is undefined)

Comment: Right, so if `selectedValue` is the ***value*** selected by the user from the dropdown why would it be a function? Can you update your question to also include all of the relevant code, i.e. this "main class component" and where you are passing a `selectedValue` prop?

Comment: thanks @DrewReese i have updated the signup index.js and view.js